# Visual Studio 2010 - .resx persistant saving

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I really was not sure how to title this question, nor what keywords to google..

**Background**: I am working on a vb project compiled for .NET 2.0 (old I know), the project has been riddled with bad development. Technology used; Dev Express v 10~, oracle 10g.

My issue is that when I open certain files, I notice that they are automatically checked out for edit on TFS, but I have done nothing but open the file. Which means I have to 'Undo pending changes' every time I simply view the code.

If I view the output window, I notice the following;

```
$/../frmWaitingRoom.resx:
   opened for edit in N51-SUMNER;Kesumner
   opened for edit in N51-HMALAN;Hmalan
$/../frmWaitingRoom.vb:
   opened for edit in N51-SUMNER;Kesumner
   opened for edit in N51-HMALAN;Hmalan
frmWaitingRoom.resx, frmWaitingRoom.vb have been automatically checked out for editing.
```

It's obvious that a resource file is referenced by the windows form, but why does it seem to 'require' editing?

If my question is duplicated or badly structured, I apologies, I haven't asked many a question.

Merry merry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some files are edited automatically by Visual Studio when they are opened. Maybe the schema is updated, or the line endings changed.

If you compare the files you should see the difference, however you will likely have to check-in the changes to prevent future checkouts.

Comment: you are correct, I noticed a style format condition was recently added with null checksums, which was setup to format the backgroud colour of a grid row should the person's age be between the checksums. So I simply added checksum values to the via the awesome DevExpress designer.